# how to force core.ignorecase to false

Tags: git, ignore-case

I have already use command `git config --global core.ignorecase false`,but each time i use command `git init` to creat a new git repository or `git clone http://xxx` to download a remote repository,`core.ignorecase` are still `true`, did i miss some configuation? Thanks !

```
OS:Windows10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it can be done by setting a template for checking out projects.
All the information how to do it it explained in here.

#### `git clone --template ...`

> Specify the directory from which templates will be used
>
> The default template directory includes some directory structure, suggested "exclude patterns".

So you can put your .gitignore in this folder and it will be used for your projects.

Comment: Thank you for raising it up. i will fix it.